# I cannot run docker on linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, docker

I try to do this :

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D

sh -c 'echo deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list'
```

Install docker

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge lxc-docker
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install docker-engine
sudo service docker start

sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

But this does not work, and when I try to run `docker ps` I got error

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: Seems like socket service is not running. What is the output of `sudo service --status-all | grep docker`?

Comment: @ddnomad Docker line `[ - ]  docker` has red color

Comment: then if I'm not mistaken (I'm not really familiar with Upstart) the service failed to load. You should find out where to see its logs to see actual errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I install my Docker Like this:

1) Check the Linux Version: `uname -a`

-> your Kernel version needs to be higher than 3.8

2) Make an Update of the System: `sudo apt-get update`

3) Adding the GPG Key:

```
sudo apt-key adv \ --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 \ --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C5609D
```

4) Check the server connection:

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main'
```

5) Downloading the Linux Image:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-generic linux-image-extra-virtual
```

6) Rebooting the System: `sudo reboot`

7) Downloading docker:

```
sudo apt install docker-engine
```

8) And finally to test, download some image:

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

It works Fine to me, the message it was because during instalation you miss to install some important things